# Como hacer una consulta en mysql, donde solo me muestre los registros que tengan ciertos caracteres o palabras

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una pequeña duda, quiero hacer una consulta en mysql, pero solo quiero que me muestre los registros que en un campo tengan cierta palabras, por ejemplo:

```
|usuarios |correo |
|---------|-------|
|test01|test01@gmail.com|
|test02|test02@hotmail.com|
|test03|test03@gmail.com|
```

Digamos que mi tabla es así, pero quiero hacer una consulta que solo me regrese a los usuarios que tienen correo Gmail o viceversa, una consulta que solo me regrese a los usuarios que tienen correo Hotmail

De antemano, muchas gracias:)

Comment: Algo como [like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) ?

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `LIKE` para esto.

```
-- Con @gmail.com
SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE correo LIKE '%@gmail.com';

-- Con @hotmail
SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE correo LIKE '%@hotmail.%';
```

Si observas bien, en la segunda consulta pusimos el wildcard al principio y al final, esto te permitirá filtrar cuentas de hotmail con todas las extensiones posibles: `.com. .es, .fr` etc. Si sólo te interesa `.com` lo pones como en la primera consulta.

Para más detalles, revisa el [tutorial sobre `LIKE`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/) y también el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: muchas gracias! ya entendi